# ASP.Net application interfering with remote host Let's Encrypt (via Plesk) installation?

Tags: angularjs, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, plesk

So, to install Let's Encrypt SSL cert, I head over to my Plesk account, pick a domain or subdomain and click on Let's Encrypt then I only have a field to put in an email address, and a button to install.

To install, Let's Encrypt sends my site an HTTP request:

> `GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/n9cD8Lpv-woEU73NhCUdFyqOYMc5hrANF_byoiaYrZc - HTTP/1.1`

If I create a fresh 'site' through Plesk, and install the cert, that GET request get's a nice 200 response and the SSL cert installs fine.

However, I had a 'sandbox' with no SSL installed, I then deployed an ASP.NetCore app to the 'sandbox' for staging and then tried to install the SSL certs.  With an ASP.NetCore application running, when Let's Encrypt sends that GET request, it results in a 404 error and the installation fails.

Has anyone run into this? What do I need to configure? Is it MVC routes or maybe the AngularJS (~1.5) routes that is interfering?

I don't see a /.well-known/* directory anywhere, I'm not sure if it is hidden, but I can't get to it, so how would I know WHAT to configure, IF I needed to configure something in routes to allow the `GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/*`?

The remote host tech support is of no help. They told me to wait 72 hours because I tried to many times and I'm just locked out (which I'm not)

Here is the actual Plesk error message

> `Let's Encrypt SSL certificate installation failed: Challenge marked as invalid. Details: Invalid response from http://my-domain.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/AJsMc3HXiOZRGaFVsMR3uZEdYu1moJ2Po62t3e6uV10 [my-ip]: 404`

I'm fairly sure I could 'work around' this by just deleting my site, installing the SSL certificate than uploading again, but I would like to know what is actually going on, and if I can handle it properly.

**AFTERTHOUGHT**

Let's Encrypt is a 30 day auto-renewing service. If my ASP.NET application is blocking the installation, then it will also block the automatic renewal, so I would have to remove my site every 30 days and re-deploy, unacceptable!

**SOLVED**
Here is the solution to this very specific scenario.

There are other work around's that will work, and of course this solution only works on IIS web servers.

[ASPNetCore MVC Routing Let Server Handle Specific Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44874279/aspnetcore-mvc-routing-let-server-handle-specific-route)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing a quick search yielded this little gem

Which seems to match your particular problem.

> To get a certificate, let’s encrypt verify that you own the domain by
> requesting a file on your server. In this case, the file is not
> accessible (status 404). Let’s understand what happened.
>
> IIS get the request, and find the associated web site. Then it
> executes handlers in order until one send the response. ASP.NET Core
> handler is the first to handle the request.
>
> The challenge file is in the folder “.well-known/…”, but by default
> ASP.NET Core serves only files located in the folder “wwwroot” => so,
> a 404 response is send to the client. ASP.NET Core has handled the
> request; therefore, the IIS Static file handler is not called.
>
> As a workaround, you can move up the “StaticFile” handler, but your
> website may not work as expected. A better solution is to instruct
> your ASP.NET Core website to send the file located in the directory
> “.well-known”.
>
> This is possible by registering it:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    //...other configs

    app.UseStaticFiles(); // wwwroot

    var wellKnownDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @".well-known");
    if (!Directory.Exists(wellKnownDirectory))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(wellKnownDirectory);

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(wellKnownDirectory),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/.well-known"),
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true // serve extensionless file
    });

    //...other configs

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

This basically routes the call for the virtual path through core which grabs the physical path and provides the file content to the caller. This should now allow for the domain to be verified and let the certificate request process flow to completion as well as automatic renewals.

Check out the article and its suggested workaround as there don't seem to be too many additional steps involved.

Comment: I gave it a shot, ran it locally, threw an exception because the directory didn't exist, (so I created them) now able to launch site via VS 2017, published it, created the directories on the server and it's still throwing an exception but since it's in the startup I can't debug it remotely to see what is the exact problem.  I'll give it another shot tomorrow, but I don't think this is going to be the solution, because even after successfully installing the Let's Encrypt on an empty site, I still don't have a /.well-known/ directory visible in the virtual directory that I can access.

Comment: @AdamVincent, Did you follow the instructions from the article? While I just made summary references to it here, there are steps in the article that I think you should be following to solve the problem like they did. Did you use the `letsencrypt-win-simple` tool they mentioned in the article? My guess would be that the folder is created as part of the process.

Comment: it's a 3rd party shared web host. executing functions server side is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: @AdamVincent ahhh, that would explain the restriction. Are able to create folders? I would then advise finding out what the tool did and perform that manually as a work around. Don't they (plesk) offer https?

Comment: While I haven't been able to resolve this issue, I'm still going to accept this answer, because it has allowed me to apply Occam's razor to put the blame definitively on the hosting provider's configuration.

Comment: @AdamVincent I am still actively looking into this as I believe using the above routing method is the preferred solution though the host provider is acknowledged as the main roadblock here. I will update you. Please update me as well if you eventually get it working. This is an interesting issue.

Comment: Yes it is interesting.  What it boils down to, is when I successfully install the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate on a "blank slate", I still do not have a visible `/.well-known/` folder. (Yes, I made sure I can see hidden / system files :-). I can even see successful  GET requests to `/.well-known/acme-challenge/<key>` So, I can only surmise that the hosting provider is redirecting requests to `./well-known` using an Alias of something of the like.

Comment: Link for reference : https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/apache-multidomain-webroot/10663

Comment: Hi @AdamVincent , if you desire to "see" the ( temporary ) created folders, there are 2 choices: 1. Configure your "panel.ini" as described at => https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/plesk-administration/panelini-configuration-file.78509/ with the ( possible ) options, described at => https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/plesk-administration/managing-lets-encrypt-settings.78586/ ( i.e.: "disable-cleanup = true" ).

Comment: 2. choice: Inspect your "panel.log", where the Plesk Let's Encrypt Extension logs it's actions. - Pls. consider as well to use a "debug log level" for the "panel.log", in order to get a more verbose output. ;-)

Comment: it is a remote host. i am a Plesk user. I am not an admin on their server and cannot modify the ini.

Comment: updated OP with the final solution for those interested.